# Building Q&A like application using Stanford NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

For my current task i am working on building Question and Answer module using Stanford NLP.
 Are there any java api from Stanford to develop Q&A related application?
Something like where i first feed my data like as
**Tiger killed dog.**
After this if i ask questions like
who killed dog ?

Whom Tiger killed ?

Is dog alive ?

It return answers as Tiger, dog , no

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is very much an open research problem, and there is no standard tool in CoreNLP to handle this. For the first two questions, however, you can look at the dependency graph (`parse` or `depparse` annotator) of the sentence, and notice that *Tiger* is `nsubj` of *killed*, whereas *dog* is the `dobj` of *killed*. This can answer simple questions like *who verb'd the noun* (`nusbj` of verb) and *noun verb'd who* (`dobj` of verb). But this is just one special case: no general purpose tool exists for this. Really, I don't know of any system, research or otherwise, that can figure out that the dog is not alive (in the sufficiently general case).